# belongs_to association conflicts when instantiating, "Validation failed... must exist" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, belongs-to

this is how I did the associations:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :lineup
  has_many :artists, :through => :lineup
  belongs_to :venue
end
```

and

```
class Lineup < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :event
end
```

this is how I'm trying to seed

```
Event.create!(name: "The Function", 
              date: DateTime.new(2016,2,3,10,0,0,'+7'), 
              venue: Venue.create!(name: "Speakeasy", address: "Lynwood Ave", zip_code: "30312"), 
              lineup: Lineup.create!(:artist => Artist.create!(name: "DJ Sliink", bio: "jersey club king")), 
              description: "free free free")
```

the error that I get is `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Event must exist` which points to the `lineup` line. I get the same message if I set `lineup: nil`, then once the `Event` is created, try to do `event1.lineup = Lineup.create!...` . What are my options for getting rid of Lineup's dependency on the Event existing? From what I understand, the problem lies in the `belongs_to` relationship, because if I take out the `artist:` from the Lineup instance creation, I also get the `Artist must exist` error.

validations:

```
> Event.validators
 => [#<ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator:0x007fcaab69fa78 @attributes=[:venue], @options={:message=>:required}>]

> Lineup.validators
 => [#<ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator:0x007fcaad988238 @attributes=[:artist], @options={:message=>:required}>, #<ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator:0x007fcaab77c7c0 @attributes=[:event], @options={:message=>:required}>]
```

without the `!`s in seed file, I get a whole different error - `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Venue(#70094220768860) expected, got Fixnum(#70094214808600)`, though still for the `event = Event.create` line.

Comment: add the validations to your post, please.

Comment: I have not written any validations. Are they automatically generated?

Answer (score 6):

In Rails 5 `belong_to` by default acts as `validates_presence_of` so in order to allow a non present relation add the `optional: true` option to the `belongs_to`. For example:

```
belongs_to :parent,
           optional: true
```

Comment: You just saved me a ton of time!  Very helpful when you are are using accepts_nested_attributes_for on the parent model.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to save the entire object on another object? Why not just the ids?

```
venue = Venue.create!(name: "Speakeasy", address: "Lynwood Ave", zip_code: "30312")
artist = Artist.create!(name: "DJ Sliink", bio: "jersey club king")
lineup = Lineup.create!(:artist_id => artist.id) 

event = Event.create!(name: "The Function", 
          date: DateTime.new(2016,2,3,10,0,0,'+7'), 
          venue_id: venue.id, 
          lineup_id: lineup.id,
          description: "free free free")
```

Check your schema to make sure venue and lineup are ids...if they aren't, what data type are you saving them as? If they're strings, you can save the names. It's unlikely that you mean to save the entire object onto event. Wouldn't make sense.

Comment: I was trying to do it like that at first, but didn't know about the `.id` part. aren't the `venue_id` and `lineup_id` attributes generated automatically when the relationships of `Event` with `Venue` and `Lineup` are made?

Comment: No. They are not automatically generated. Check your db/schema file to make sure that you have venue_id and lineup_id as attributes. If they aren't there you'll need to run a migration. Simply writing `has_many` and `belongs_to` doesn't alter the composition of your database.

Comment: I see. I'm still getting the `Event must exist` error. What should I look for in schema or anywhere?

Comment: Ok, so the problem must be with the `event_id` parameter. But, it needs it, doesn't it? A lineup can belong to only one event. Or the key for a lineup in the event instance should be sufficient enough?

Comment: post your schema in a gist: https://gist.github.com/ and post the link and I'll take a look.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any validations? In the rails console, for each model, run `Model.validators`...for instance: `Artist.validators` `Lineup.validators` etc...also remove the ! after all of your creates. That forces things to rollback when they otherwise may not.

Comment: yay! I finally got it to fully seed. turns out it was the `.id`s for event and lineup inside `Event.create`, didn't need them.